# How to lock a SQLite database file (.sdb) from file system access

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, sqlite

I'm looking to lock the SQLite database file from outside changes other than its target application. Is this possible?

For example, I have a WPF application that I would like to have read/write access to the DB without allowing other applications to write to it. I understand that you can create exclusive locks via transaction, but is there a way to "lock the database" for the entire duration of the application?

Note that read access is fine, I just do not want any 3rd party applications (DB Browser) being able to make changes while the WPF application is running.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't just want to lock the DB for a certain transaction. But rather limit access to the file in general. I would suggest you look for a solution on file system level.

Just limit the write access to the file to administrator accounts and the account used to execute your wpf application. That should be enough.